# Imread on Raspberry TypeError

Tags: python, opencv, blob, typeerror

I am trying the Blob detection Example from LearnOpenCV on the Raspberry Pi, but continue to get errors om the imread file. The error is "TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation".

This is the code:

```
import picamera.array
import picamera
import numpy as np
import cv2

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as stream:
        camera.resolution = (320,240)

        while True:
            camera.capture(stream, 'bgr', use_video_port=True)

            im = cv2.imread(stream.array, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
            keypoints = detector.detect(im)
            im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
            cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is that just the error message?

Comment: Indeed, the error is "TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation" on line "im = cv2.imread(stream.array, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)"

Comment: Where did you get the code? And what version of opencv do you have?

Comment: I actually made it myself by copying parts of other scripts. The Blob detection is coming from https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: The problem is that in the example shown in the link uses an image, instead in your code you use a video.

Comment: Must change `im = cv2.imread(stream.array, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` to `im = cv2.cvtColor(stream.array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: Indeed. So I want it for video.

Comment: Can you try the change?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Eyllanesc was correct:

Must change im = cv2.imread(stream.array, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) to im = cv2.cvtColor(stream.array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)